# Twitter Integration for IOS 4.3

Tags: ios, twitter, sdk, ios4

It's easily to integrate Twitter in iOS 5 (Twitter.framework) and iOS 6 (Social.framework).

What about iOS 4.3?

What I have tried:

1) I tried **Sharekit**, it's not working properly, it's hard to install, and I get a lot of Xcode errors and files not found error after installation.

2) I also tried **DETweetComposeViewController** + **unoffcial-twitter-sdk**, I also get many errors, one of them is **OAuth+UserDefaults.h** *not* found.

What's the `best way for iOS 4.3`?

Thanks

Comment: WHy bother with iOS 4 support? You can only support 4.3 and so few people are still using 4.3 that there is no point in putting much effort into it. iOS 7 will be out in a few months.

Comment: I meant iOS 4.3 not 4.0.
I cannot support 4.3 if I don't have Twitter integration for it.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use  "MGtwitter Engine" for ios 4.3

you get it form following link

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine

i hope it may help you.

Comment: It's not working perfectly either, the problem I don't have iOS 4.3 simulator to test it, I guess I will just skip supporting iOS 4.3.